# Can fixed disk 2 become fixed disk 1 in DOS?

Tags: ms-dos

I was wondering if anyone knows how to make fixed disk 2 fixed disk 1 in ms dos.

Thanks
-Gabe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a tricky bootloader, before DOS gets loaded to hook into the Bios and swap the ID's.
I usually use the [Plop](https://www.plop.at/en/bootmanagers.html) bootloader, which can do this and a number of other nifty things as well.
(Like allowing a computer without USB boot support to boot from a USB stick.)
There are probably others around as well, but I can't recall any specific examples at this time.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that out. Until further notice, your post is the answer to this question.